# Nginx, Django - Domain gives 400 (Bad Request) but reaching through IP Adress des work

Tags: django

I added the domain to allowed hosts already like that:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["161.35.74.202", "*.example.de", "example.de"]
```

This is how my nginx sites available file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 161.35.74.202 example.de;
```

I now tried adding a "+" to Allowed Hosts (+=), which again did not change anything.

I am really frustrated right now because I cant find the mistake here.
I tried a lot and would be really really grateful for an advice. Thanks